# Detect client disconnect in streaming Response (server sent events) Flask

Tags: python, sockets, flask, server, server-sent-events

I'm writing a Flask server using SSE and running into the same problem as [Flask server sent events socket exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479902/flask-server-sent-events-socket-exception). Looking for better answers because leaving the client responsible is not good if the for example the browser does not exit gracefully.

Within the context of code from the question above, the Flask server sends events to the client using a Response of `mimetype="text/event-stream"` and the response object is just a co-routine which continuously yields data. If a client disconnects without calling close(), the server gets an exception `Errno 32 Broken Pipe`.

Putting a `try` around the return statement catches an error, but it doesnt stop the log below from printing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 508, in handle_one_response
    self.run_application()
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 495, in run_application
    self.process_result()
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 486, in process_result
    self.write(data)
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 376, in write
    self._write(data)
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 369, in _write
    self._sendall(data)
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/pywsgi.py", line 355, in _sendall
    self.socket.sendall(data)
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 460, in sendall
    data_sent += self.send(_get_memory(data, data_sent), flags)
  File "/Users/miluo/development/build/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/gevent/socket.py", line 437, in send
    return sock.send(data, flags)
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
{'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'text/event-stream',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'no-cache',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_HOST': '0.0.0.0:1234',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'localhost:1122',
 'HTTP_REFERER': 'localhost:1122/',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36',
 'PATH_INFO': '/1',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '51323',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'localhost',
 'SERVER_PORT': '1234',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'gevent/1.0 Python/2.6',
 'werkzeug.request': None,
 'wsgi.errors': <open file '<stderr>', mode 'w' at 0x105c991e0>,
 'wsgi.input': <gevent.pywsgi.Input object at 0x10753a5d0>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': False,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)} failed with error
```

Comment: `Threaded server` ? client put query and escape ! Try create client side event otherwise you need check every time.

Comment: harmless but these messages really cluster up the logs and is just annoying in general