# Broken pipe error and connection reset by peer 104

Tags: python, bottle, broken-pipe, sigpipe

I'm using `Bottle` server to implement my own server using an implementation not so far away from the simple "hello world" [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/)  , my own implementation is (without the routing section of course):
`bottleApp =bottle.app()
 bottleApp.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80, debug=true)`

My server is keep getting unresponsive all the time and then I get in the Browser: `Connection reset by peer`, `broken pipe errno 32`
The logs give me almost exactly the same stack traces such as in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063416/python-basehttpserver-how-do-i-catch-trap-broken-pipe-errors).

Here are my own logs:
[image: Broken pipe stack trace]
[image: connection reset by peer stack trace]

What I tried so far, without success:

1. Wrapping the server run line with try except, something like, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180095/how-to-handle-a-broken-pipe-sigpipe-in-python/180922#180922)   the answer of "mhawke".
   This stopped the error messages in logs, apparently because I caught them in `except` clause, but problem is that when catching the exception like that it means that we have been thrown out of the `run` method context, and I want to catch it in a way it will not cause my server to fall.
   I don't know if its possible without touching the inner implementations files of `bottle`.
2. Adding this before server run line:
   `from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
   signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)`
   As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207708/ioerror-errno-32-broken-pipe-python), but it seems that it didn't had any impact on not getting Broken pipe\connection reset errors and server responsiveness.
3. I thought of trying also the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063416/python-basehttpserver-how-do-i-catch-trap-broken-pipe-errors), but I don't have any idea where to locate this code in the context of the `bottle` server.

Comment: To get help on this, I think you'll need to post the code for a complete minimal example of the problem.

Comment: There is really no additional code relevant than I already wrote or mentioned, the server is just set and forget

Comment: To debug this, we need to be able to run the exact same thing you are running.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue or a firewall.

if you really need to listen on port 80, then you need to run with a privileged account. Also you will probably need to open port 80 for tcp traffic.

I can see your using something that appears to be Posix (Linux/Unix/OSx) If you post what OS you are using I can edit this answer to be more specific as to how to open the firewall and execute privileged commands (probably `sudo` but who knows).